# SQL join order and conditions

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I've got 3 tables that I want to join and filter on some conditions.

I've first wrote this query:

```
select * from table1 t1
    left join (select * from table2 where table2.fieldX=...) t2
        on t1.id_12=t2.id_12
        left join table3
            on t2.id_23=t3.id_23
where t1.fieldY=...
```

Then I wanted to make it looks like more canonical by rewritting it like that:

```
select * from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
        on t1.id_12=t2.id_12
        left join table3
            on t2.id_23=t3.id_23
where table2.fieldX=...
and t1.fieldY=...
```

But it does not give the same result.
I dont't understand why...

Do you?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `t2` instead of `table2` in where clause in second SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put `table2.fieldX=...` in the where clause you eliminate all rows from table1 that do not have a corresponding row in table2. Effectively you are changing the left join into an inner join.

Instead, you can apply the table2 filter in the join itself:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id_12 = t2.id_12 AND t2.fieldX = ...
    LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.id_23 = t3.id_23
WHERE
    t1.fieldY = ...
```

Comment: Thanks Tobsey, I understand now why the 2 requests were differents.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the inner select where on the second query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 t1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2
           on t1.id_12=t2.id_12 
       LEFT JOIN table3 
           on t2.id_23=t3.id_23 
WHERE  t1.fieldY=...
       and t2.fieldX=...
```

Comment: You can use `t2` instead of `table2` in where clause.